# How does the retry statement work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iterator, retry-logic

I'm just getting started in Ruby, but the manual I'm following seems to be outdated. I've been doing some research but I've been unable to find a clear answer.

The manual used the 'retry' keyword inside of a method that should act as a loop, but it is used without a begin/rescue block, and the behavior seems pretty different when you force the 'retry' keyword to be inside of a begin/rescue block.

I've tried many things:
-The first one was using the "begin" keyword at the start of the method and a 'raise' at the retry point, followed by the respective 'rescue; retry; end;'.
-The last one was using the 'begin/rescue' block outside, wrapping the call of the method.

Following the logic in the manual, only the last one worked as it should.

There some examples:

The code in the manual is as follows:

```
def WHILE(cond)
  return if not cond
  yield
  retry
end
i=0; WHILE(i<3) {print i; i+=1}
```

result:
012

I've tried the following:

```
def WHILE(cond)
  begin
    return if not cond
    yield
    raise
  rescue
    retry
  end
end
i=0; WHILE(i<3) {print i; i+=1}
```

result:
*infinite numbers*

```
def WHILE(cond)
  return if not cond
  yield
end
i=0; begin; WHILE(i<3) {print i; i+=1}; raise; rescue; retry; end
```

result:
012 *(plus an obvious infinite loop printing nothing)*

I expect you from taking me out of this existential doubt, but here's MY conclusion.

Before the obligatory use of the begin/rescue block for the 'retry' keyword, it could be used in a way that it can't anymore, **repeating the call** of a method in spite of **being inside of that method**.

Now, it just jumps to the 'begin' statement.

But i'm unsure of this, and I need confirmation. And if so, **is there any form to recover that kind of use?**

Thanks.

Comment: "is there any form to recover that kind of use" Sorry, it's unclear: what was it that you wanted `retry` to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I just wonder if it could be used to get the same result that it had in the first example, before being forced to be inside a "begin / rescue" block. Which seems to be, for me, being able to recall the method with an updated parameter.

Comment: The first example does not work in Ruby 2.6. You get an error on line 4: Invalid retry (SyntaxError)

Comment: @tadman I know, I found that it was forced to be inside of a rescue block in Ruby 2.3.1 (before that, it worked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `WHILE` does not behave like a regular `while` since in your case `i<3` is evaluated at call time *once*. The `while` statement evaluates it each time.

If you want to write a `while` equivalent it's important that your condition be something that *can be* evaluated, not something that is *already* evaluated.

You can fix that by accepting a Proc as a condition:

```
def so_long_as(cond)
  loop do
    return unless cond.call

    yield
  end
end
```

Then you call it like this:

```
i = 0
so_long_as(-> { i < 3 }) do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

Where that now prints `012` and terminates properly.

What's important to note is that `retry` only works within a `begin`/`end` context, not a regular method, that now you have to use `redo` instead:

```
i = 0
redone = false
so_long_as(-> { i < 3 }) do
  print i
  unless (redone)
    redone = true
    redo
  end
  i += 1
end
```

Where that prints `0012` now.

There's been [some significant changes to how `redo` and `retry` work](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/05/redo-retry-next.html) that are worth reading up on.

Comment: Thanks! It was really explanatory. So I could do something like this:

`def WHILE(cond)
    begin
        return if not cond.call
        yield
        raise
    rescue
        retry
    end
end

i=0; WHILE(-> {i<3}) {print i; i+=1}`

I know that this is pretty ugly and it's better to use a regular loop, but now I'm sure that my thoughs were for the right path.

Comment: So the method's parameter just needed to be "updated" (or reevaluated) for its evaluation at the return statement. And the retry keyword seemed to do that before 2.3.1.

Comment: You need what's loosely called a "dynamic" value, one that can be repeatedly evaluated to test against changing conditions. A lambda (Proc) closure does this job nicely, hence the first argument. They did change how `retry` worked in Ruby rather dramatically I think to avoid it doing two different and somewhat contradictory things depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using `loop` defeats a bit the goal of the given exercise, hence I have two other solutions using `redo` or `retry` and no loop which I'd like to share.

If you have no idea how I may have done that I suggest you try before looking at the solutions.

### 1. `retry`

```rb
def _while(cond, _loop=Class.new(RuntimeError))
  raise _loop if cond.call
rescue _loop
  yield
  retry
end

i = 0
_while(-> { i < 3 }) do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

### 2. `redo`

```rb
def _while(cond)
  proc do
    if cond.call
      yield
      redo
    end
  end.call
end

i = 0
_while(-> { i < 3 }) do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```